# É possível manipular variáveis de SESSÃO para realizar SQL Injection?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, segurança, sql-injection

Não sou especialista em *cyber* ataques e estou com uma pequena dúvida em relação à segurança dos meus projetos. Basicamente umas das formas que eu me previno de injeções **SQL** é criando uma função "**tratarString()**", por exemplo, e todos os dados que entram externamente eu os filtro através dessa função. Beleza! Funciona...!

Sei que é possível manipular externamente os **COOKIES** de um browser de forma maliciosa a ponto de, quando a aplicação utilizar os **$_COOKIES**, a injeção acontecer. Portanto também os filtro através da função acima.

A pergunta é... as variáveis de **SESSÃO** também são possíveis manipular maliciosamente? Devo me prevenir com elas também? É possível manipulá-las externamente, assim como os **COOKIES**?

Se sim, tô ferrado. Pois todos os projetos que criei, não precavi a injeção via **SESSÃO** e os primeiros que fiz eu nem utilizei **PDO** para conexão no banco. E pior, lembro-me de trabalhar diretamente com as variareis de sessão nas instruções **SQL**.

Algum palpite?

Agradeço o apoio.
Abraços!!

Comment: Isso geralmente é o primeiro indicativo de problema: _"umas das formas que eu me previno de injeções SQL é criando uma função "tratarString()"_, por exemplo, e todos os dados que entram externamente eu os filtro através dessa função." - Se usa MySQL, já tem a função correta pra isso. Não existe razão para fazer uma separada (tipo aqueles malucos que ficam divulgando aquela porcaria de função "AntiInjection()" nos fóruns por aí). Uma vez que a string seja sanitizada da maneira certa ao montar a _query_, usando a função nativa, a injeção não ocorre.

Comment: SQL Injection só ocorre se você usa concatenação string para criar queries, ex.: `string sql= "select * from tabela where campo="+ variavel_campo`. Você injetar um sql na `variavel_campo`, como  '1 or 1=1;Drop table umatabela;'. Um jeito simples de precaver SQL Injection é usar parâmetros ao invés de concatenação

Comment: Alternativamente à função correta (no caso da mysqli, por exemplo é a mysqli_real_escape_string), você pode fazer o binding de valores, mas lembre-se que isso é opcional. Ao contrario do que os "entendidos" divulgam, o binding (nativo, não o simulado da PDO, por exemplo, que é mais uma espécie de enfeite) não foi feito para evitar injeção, e sim para reaproveitamento de query.

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda pessoal. Hoje eu já utilizo MySqli, pdo, parametros e, às vezes, funções nativas. A minha dúvida é somente em relação à manipulação de SESSÃO pois tenho diversos projetos já publicados que eu lembro de não ter essa segurança toda. Minha preocupação não é com os meus próximos projetos, e sim com os que eu fiz antigamente. Entende?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como os amigos comentaram acima é importante utilizar métodos já testados e consequentemente seguros para filtragem dos dados, como o `mysql_real_escape_string`.

No entanto, como sua dúvida está relacionada a SQL Injection via variáveis de sessão, a resposta é talvez. Um cliente não consegue modificar uma variável de sessão diretamente, visto que ela só é acessada no lado do servidor. No entanto, se a partir de más práticas de programação o desenvolvedor armazene informações que podem ser manipuladas pelo usuário em variáveis de sessão a resposta pode ser sim. Só que essa é uma manipulação indireta. Um exemplo de "manipulação indireta" da sessão pode ser vista aqui: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2070/altering-a-session-variable-in-php-via-xss

É importante ressaltar que todos os dados que podem ser manipulados pelo usuário merecem atenção e devem ser sanitizados.

Answer (score 1):

Se a sessão armazena algum valor que é informado pelo usuário: sim. Uma caso comum seria:

1. O usuário insere o nome de `"or"1"="1`
2. Você faz um `INSERT tabela(`nome`) VALUES ("\"or"1"="1")`
   Neste caso nenhum "SQL Injection" é realizado, você simplesmente tem um nome como uma string qualquer.
3. Depois, o usuário acessa uma página, onde você recupera o `nome` do banco e cria uma session com ela, o que irá resultaria em `$_SESSION['nome'] = "or"1"="1`.
4. Depois, você resolve fazer um `SELECT * WHERE nome = "$_SESSION['nome']"`, neste caso ficará exatamente: `SELECT * WHERE nome = ""or"1"="1"`, assim obtendo todos os dados ao invés do especifico para o nome.